# URL rewrite to ignore php $_GET statement

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a url like:

```
http://www.site.com/profile.php?id=$id
```

And I want it to end up like:

```
http://www.site.com/$id
```

How could I do this in PHP or in htaccess?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]

Comment: write your URL scheme using htacess & link it in your php file in according to the URL scheme. Refer http://dzineblog.com/2012/05/build-a-custom-url-structure-with-htaccess-rewrites.html

Comment: Thanks all. I was getting confused with the technicalities. I appreciate your redundancy in answering my common question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a rewrite rule in htaccess such as

`RewriteRule ([0-9]+) profile.php?id=$1 [L]`

This would rewrite anything with a 0-9 character to profile.php and pass the number in the query string. So you could do

`site.com/1`

Which would be

`site.com/profile.php?id=1`

Answer (score 1):

N number of discussion gone already here. Anyway, here it is. :)

Your htacces rewrite rule,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Way to link in your PHP files,

```
<a href="http://www.site.com/$id">Your URL</a>
```

Make sure to replace $id with your values.

FYI, `http://www.site.com/profile.php?id=$id` will also works, avoid using it & use mask URL like i quoted above. :)